# Bandwidth Limits & HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to throttle a HttpWebRequest? I can call GetResponse() but that will download the response at it's own speed and I may want to limit the rate of download.

So far I can't see anything that would let me?

Comment: Have you tried `GetResponse().GetResponseStream()`? You can read it in chunks per certain time interval.

Comment: GetResponse() gets the response, by the time GetResponseStream() is called the response is already downloaded.

Comment: @Lloyd, when you call GetResponse(), it doesn't download the whole response... it downloads the headers, and the beginning of the response body, but not the whole body (unless it's small enough).

Comment: Heh yeh I know this now, thanks for replying though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas Levesque said, `GetResponse()` downloads the headers and the beginning and not the whole item like previously thought.

This means that I can read in chunks and throttle as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the Range Http header, if the server supports Range headers, to tell the server to only send back part of the response?